# Augment the express-serve-static-core module Version 4.17.14 is not working with typescript

Tags: typescript, express, types

With `"@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.17.13"`,
augmenting `express-serve-static-core` is working fine:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import express from 'express'

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Request {
    prisma: PrismaClient
  }
}

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 8000


const prisma = new PrismaClient()
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.prisma = prisma
  next()
})
```

When I upgrade to With `"@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.17.14"` this `express` server is not working anymore:
`Error: Property 'prisma' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.ts(2339)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By updating other packages it worked:

```
    "@types/express": "4.17.9",
    "@types/node": "14.14.10",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.17.14",
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by updating devDependencies
from `"@types/express": "^4.17.0"`, to `"@types/express": "^4.17.2"`,
and add new dependency `"@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.17.20"`,
without updating typescript my current typescript version is `"typescript": "~3.8.3"`